# How to reset root view controller

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to reset the root view controller? With reset I mean resetting it to its initial state so `viewDidLoad` will be called again. I'm using a `UITabBarController` and when I logout I want all the tabs previously loaded to be unloaded.

Comment: Create new instance and set to root view controller may help

Comment: Why not use `viewWillAppear` to reset the state?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does viewDidload method call again on going back to a screen in navigation controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778426/does-viewdidload-method-call-again-on-going-back-to-a-screen-in-navigation-contr)

Comment: How is my question a duplicate @himanth? I asked how to reset the root view controller, not how and when viewDidLoad is called

Comment: @DanielTovesson Dont be panic bro, others will understand your quest according to your content or may be some get misunderstanding from it.

Comment: @DanielTovesson By the way it is possible. You need to set your required `UIViewController` after the logout as the rootViewController of NavigationController.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by setting the instance of TabBarController to *rootViewController* on logout action.

**Swift 3:**

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let tabBarController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = tabBarController
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

**Objective C:**

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setRootViewController:tabBarController];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: key window is deprecated now in ios 13. Please give latest solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using navigation controller on `Tabbarcontroller` then navigate to that navigation controller otherwise go to `Tabbarcontroller` as-

```
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
 let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let tabBar = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! TabBarController
 appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBar
 appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `view` property of `UIViewController` to `nil`

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view = nil
```

it will force `UIViewController` to init his life cycle from a beginning after next call to `self.view`